# Information to redact from Terraform debug logs?

Tags: terraform

When submitting GitHub issues, it's asked that we provide debug logs with the ticket. Does anyone know what are good fields/data to redact from the log?

For example, the output will include requests to AWS'S STS service which provides auth data. I imagine that would be good to remove, yeah? Should usernames, account ID's, user arns, etc be removed too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when submitting them, they have a GPG key to hide your secrets from the entire internet. Definitely do that.

Second, when I had to do it I paged through the whole thing. Some of the things I hid:

- **Netblock information**. Mostly transferring to different subnets. If some data leaks, targeted attackers will have an unexpectedly hard time mapping our inside network once they get a way to probe it.
- **Exact names**. This took some work, but some judicious sed work replaced all the `chicago-bind` with `dns01` and such. Bind for DNS isn't a bad guess, but mongodb vs cassandra is more useful for figuring out a targeted attack.
- **AWS account numbers.**. These are part of the ARN and are quite sed-able.
- **Actual secrets**. Some Terraform resources require things like passwords and access-keys. You may be surprised how much of that is in there if you've never looked at a debug dump before.

It's a lot of work, some of it manual.

Comment: Oh man, simplest solution being to just encrypt the log itself! Thanks!